# Change a property that belongs to a XAML of another class C#. (WinUI 3 for Desktops)

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm in the "Code" class and I'm trying to modify a property of an object in the "MainWindow" class.
I want to modify the Text property of the "DriveC" object.
My current code is reporting the error: The name 'DriveC' does not exist in the current context.

I know that if I change the class signature from "public class Code" to "public sealed partial class MainWindow" then I will have access to that property and the error will not occur.

However, for study purposes, I need this class not to be a partial type. I need to be able to instantiate this class inside other classes.

So what needs to be modified in the code so that the "Code" class has access to properties that are in the XAML of another class?

[image]

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code is the fastest way I've seen here to get your question downvoted and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [XAML namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namescopes)

Try using [FrameworkElement.FindName](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname?view=winui-3.0) or x:Bind Text to a property that you change from code elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> So what needs to be modified in the code so that the "Code" class has access to properties that are in the XAML of another class?

Well, you need to get a reference to the other class one way or another.

To get a reference to the `MainWindow` from any class in your app, you could change the modifier of the `m_window` field in `App.xaml.cs` to `internal` or `public`:

```
internal Window m_window;
```

You could then get a reference to the window in your `Code` class like this:

```
var window = (App.Current as App)?.m_window as MainWindow;
if (window != null)
    window.DriveC.Text = GetHDDSize(@"C:\");
```